# Filtering/Cleaning a Dataset using R/Python/Unix

Tags: python, r, filtering

I was wondering if anyone is aware of a filtering process/function I could use any method (R/Python/Unix bash).

So my dataset looks like:

```
Gene  Chromosome Counts ...
x
x
x
x
```

Now, I have a different text file which contains a selection of the Genes from the dataset above. So I am looking for a function that would allow an input file to filter out the Gene column and leave intact the Chromosome - Counts columns.

The reason I can't do this in excel is that my dataset is really huge and it crashes my computer everytime, and its very exhausting to do this manually.

Also, I am not a programmer that's why I cannot code a script for this I tired in the past it was a massive failure.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to filter the "Gene" column like in Excel, right? Try the subset function in R.

Working with 1 gene:

```
Gene1 <- subset(df, Gene %in% c("Gene1"))
```

df is the name you gave to your data frame when you read it in R.

Working with n gene:

```
genes_of_interest <- c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4")

Genes <- subset(df, Gene %in% c(genes_of_interest))
```

Comment: would this work with 100 genes ?

Comment: No, to work with 100 genes you should create a new variable and insert it in the function above.

Comment: ah ok, I thin that you are right it is still worth typing 100 genes rather than manually work it out on excel

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Your question may benefit from an **example dataset**, as this simple response may not work on all data.

Given the [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file genes.txt:

```
Gene,Chromosome,Etc
a,1,x
b,2,x
c,2,y
```

The command
`awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $2,$3}' genes.txt | tee genes-edit.txt`

will print

```
Chromosome,Etc
1,x
2,x
2,y
```

and output the same to the file genes-edit.txt